# Button is not calling OnClickListener with first click

Tags: java, android, xml, button

I am trying to develop a **[Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)** in page, where I have Username, password and a button. When I click the button for the first time, nothing happens, but when I click the button for the second time, then it works properly. I am confused, why it is happening ?

> activity_login.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/splash_bg"
tools:context=".LoginActivity" >
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_margin="30dp" >

<EditText
    style="@style/EditText1"
    android:id="@+id/userEditText"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:hint="username" />
 <EditText
    style="@style/EditText1"
    android:id="@+id/passEditText"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:hint="password" />
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/locationSpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:popupBackground="#ffffff"
    style="@style/EditText1"
   android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />
<Button
   style="@style/Button1"
   android:focusable="true"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
   android:onClick="onLoginClick"
   android:text="continue"
         />
```

loginActivity.java

```
 @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    public void onLoginClick(View view) {
        String username = mUserEditText.getText().toString();
        String password = mPassEditText.getText().toString();
        String location = mLocationData.get(
                mLocationSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toLowerCase();
        if (username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
            CreatorMessenger
                    .getInstance()
                    .showMessage(this, "Error!!",
                            "You need to enter username and password both to continue!!");
            return;
        }
        User user;
        user = new User(username);/*
                             * }
                                 */
        user.setLocation(location);
        AppManager.getInstance().setLoggedInUser(user);

        APICaller.getInstance().login(username, password, location);
    }
```

Comment: Use Logger to see in logcat if it is entering the method or not. You will see it is not beacuse the focusableInTouchMode param.

Comment: SO what should I do, please help me ??

Comment: Maybe my answer to this similar question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42092582/1617737

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes Yes I got the answer, after a lot of RND, I got the solution, I just need to implement setOnClickListener(), and setOnFocusChangeListener(). So I am  putting here the solution.

> ActivityLogin.java

```
 buttonLogin= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
    buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("hello", "hellow");
            String username = mUserEditText.getText().toString();
            String password = mPassEditText.getText().toString();
            String location = mLocationData.get(mLocationSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toLowerCase();
            if(username.isEmpty()||password.isEmpty()){
            popbox();
                return;
            }
            User user;
            user = new User(username);
            user.setLocation(location);
            AppManager.getInstance().setLoggedInUser(user);
            APICaller.getInstance().login(username, password, location);
        }
    });
    buttonLogin.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            v.performClick();
        }
    }
});
}
```

> activity_login.xml

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
        style="@style/Button1"

        android:text="continue"
         />
```

Comment: So you are basically calling onClick() on OnFocus() method. Disabling focus should have worked the same but glad this worked out.

Comment: Actually works well for my issue. I needed the button to be focusable so that my editText views onFocusChange event gets fired when i click the button, and also i needed the button click event to be fired on the first click. If i remove its focusability, the edittext doesnt lose its focus and its event doesnt fire, and without the focus change listener on the button it had to be pressed twice. so, thank you :)

Answer (score 27):

You are setting `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`
Hence on 1st click it receives focus.

Refer [Android button - How to set focusable to true and still accept onClick listener on first click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970734/android-button-how-to-set-focusable-to-true-and-still-accept-onclick-listener)

Comment: I removed android:focusableInTouchMode="true" but still it is not working properly

Comment: Did you rebuild your project and then deployed?

Comment: No I remove it in existing project.]

Comment: Unless auto build is enables. You need to rebuild the project for your changes to take effect. So rebuild your project and try again.

Comment: I never knew a purpose of the attribute is that. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

Set this -

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

to this -

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

on button.

Explanation - If you'll make the button focusable then on first click the focus is passed to the button, then the click is passed on second touch. EditText is a focusable View which gains focus first and therefore other views must first regain the focus from EditText, unless they do not need focus to work, just like buttons. If you just need the OnClick function, then you don't need focus, so you can spre one extra click.

PS: Although it shouldn't require, but setting `android:focusable` to false will help too, if the first one doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

if in your xml in button, or img, or liner layout has:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

To resolve, just
remove this.

Answer (score 1):

I suggested to use request focus in the "onCreate()" method.

When you using `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` you may don't want the focus catch by an 'EditText' field.

For example:
 1. An activity has a view contain -> android:focusableInTouchMode
 2. You open a Fragment Dialog, but the back button need click two times to fire it.
 3. You should call requestFocus() after the Fragment Dialog onCreateView()