# ListView footer only selectable after selecting listview item first

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-button

So i have searched and searched and tried every method ive seen but nothing seems to solve my problem. My listview generates with custom adapter, i add the footer view, and onTouchMethod, and i know that it is competing for focus with the lsitview and the listview is winning as i have read about this error. But perhaps there is something i cant see and i am missing.

I need the footer view to be selectable at all times, Right now it is only selectable after an item is selected in listview and then everything works as its suppose to. But on first load on the listview, the footer is unresponsive.

Here is my code.

```
customAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.itemlistrow, store_data);
    customAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);

    listView.addFooterView(none_of_the_above, null, false);
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, final View view,
                int position, long id) {



                none_of_the_above.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                            v.setSelected(true);
                            view.setSelected(false);
                            view.setActivated(false);
                            view.clearFocus();

                            Log.e("NoneOFTheAboveButton:onTouch", "clicked");
                            none_of_the_above.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.store_setup2_found_selection_boxes_modified_states));
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });

listView.clearFocus();
                none_of_the_above.setSelected(false);
                view.setSelected(true);
                view.setActivated(true);

                selectedPosition = position;
                customAdapter.setSelectedPosition(selectedPosition);

}


    });
```

my footer button xml

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/none_of_the_above"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/store_setup2_found_selection_boxes_modified_states"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="NONE OF THE ABOVE" />
```

Listview xml:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/selection_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >
```

I have now taken the onTouchMethod out of the OnItemClick of listview and put it above and it receives click on first try. But now the Listview doesnt lose focus when clicked first and then the footer is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by putting onTouch method outside onItemClick as well as one inside onItemClick to interact with listview when listview has been selected.

also added `listview.clearChoices()`inside the onTouch method outside onIemClick

Answer (score 0):

Move your

```
        none_of_the_above.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    v.setSelected(true);
                    view.setSelected(false);
                    view.setActivated(false);
                    view.clearFocus();

                    Log.e("NoneOFTheAboveButton:onTouch", "clicked");
                    none_of_the_above.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.store_setup2_found_selection_boxes_modified_states));
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

outside of `listView.setOnItemClickListener()`. Put it before this line, not in `onItemClick()` method.

Then in `onItemClick()` method put:

```
none_of_the_above.setTag(view);
```

And in `onTouch()` use this:

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    v.setSelected(true);
                    (v.getTag()).setSelected(false);
                    (v.getTag()).setActivated(false);
                    (v.getTag()).clearFocus();

                    Log.e("NoneOFTheAboveButton:onTouch", "clicked");
                    v.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.store_setup2_found_selection_boxes_modified_states));
                }
```

Comment: Doing this works and it receives click, but then the listview focus doesn't behave properly(doesn't get unselected when footer is clicked). The footer also doesn't hold onto focus and when i go to continue to next activity, my check to see if an item was selected gives error.

Comment: Maybe your Footer layout have `GONE` visibility bu default.

Comment: After some testing, only the listview wasn't losing focus on footer click. so the footer was behaving properly except for the listview not losing focus on its click. This last addition you've added, gives me cannot resolve methods for all the v.getTag() methods.

Answer (score 0):

In your Button xml:

```
android:clickable="false"
```

The onItemClickListener will not work, if clickable is true for the element within the list.

[android:clickable="true" mean's that it's not clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894815/android-androidclickable-true-means-that-its-not-clickable)

You will also need to set:

```
android:focusable="false
```

As the first click is receiving the focus.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20473421/3956566

Comment: this did not work. Tried both. setting focusable to false gives me indexoutofbounds exception as well as not working.

Comment: The listview has a tablelayout with a bunch of textviews. And the button is just the footer. My issue now is not the footer receiving focus and selectable on first click, but instead now when clicking on the listview and then the footer, the listview doesnt lose focus.

Comment: any idea why this is happening?